# Python* to boost::python::object

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost, boost-python

I am trying to build a Python module in C++ that transforms a 2D vector into a Numpy 2D array. What is incorrect here - presumably there is some transformation needed to a boost python object from PyObject*?

```
boost::python::object build_day(int year, int day) {

  PyObject* arr;
  const int HEIGHT = 5;
  const int WIDTH = 5;

  std::vector<std::vector<float> > array(WIDTH, std::vector<float>(HEIGHT));

  npy_intp dims[2] = {WIDTH, HEIGHT};
  arr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, NPY_FLOAT, &array);

  return arr; 
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(sumpar) {
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("build_day", build_day, args("year", "day"));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`boost::python::object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/object.html) provides a generalized interface to Python objects.  To construct one from a `PyObject*`, one must first construct a [`boost::python::handle<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/handle.html), which is essentially a smart pointer designed to manage reference-counted Python objects (`PyObject*` or derived types).   One often uses `handle<>` between the boundary between Boost.Python's higher-level code and the Python/C API.

```cpp
namespace python = boost::python;
PyObject* py_object = get_py_object();
python::handle<> handle(py_object);
boost::python object(handle);
```

Note that the `handle` will share ownership of the `PyObject*`, and during destruction, it will decrease the reference count on the `PyObject` it is managing.  Thus, during construction, it is important to specify whether or not `handle<>` needs to increase the reference count of `PyObject*`.

If `PyObject` has already had its reference count increased, then use:

```cpp
namespace python = boost::python;
PyObject* py_object = ...;
python::handle<> handle(py_object);
python::object object(handle);
```

If `PyObject` has not had its reference count increased, and the handle must do it, then use the [`borrowed()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/handle.html#borrowed-spec) function during construction:

```cpp
namespace python = boost::python;
PyObject* py_object = ...;
python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(py_object));
python::object object(handle);
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0928cccf1b9c1685) constructing a `boost::python::object` from a `PyObject*`:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

// Mocks...
enum { NPY_FLOAT };
typedef int npy_intp;
PyObject* PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(int, npy_intp*, int, void*)
{
  return PyString_FromString("hello world");
}

boost::python::object build_day(int year, int day)
{
  const int HEIGHT = 5;
  const int WIDTH = 5;

  std::vector<std::vector<float> > array(
      WIDTH, std::vector<float>(HEIGHT));

  npy_intp dims[2] = {WIDTH, HEIGHT};

  namespace python = boost::python;
  PyObject* arr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, NPY_FLOAT, &array);
  python::handle<> handle(arr);
  return python::object(handle);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("build_day", &build_day, python::args("year", "day"));
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> day = example.build_day(1, 2);
>>> assert(day)
```

---

Note that to create a minimal complete example, the above example has a mocked `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData()` that simply returns Python string.  It is important to consult the documentation to determine if the `PyObject*` is borrowed or not, and if there are any lifetime requirements between the object and its arguments.  In the case of [`PyArray_SimpleNewFromData()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData), the returned `PyObject*`:

- already has its reference count increased
- the lifetime of the underlying memory provided to the array must be at least as long as the returned `PyObject`.  The `build_day()` function in the original question fails to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the variables and objects provided by boost::python, so if you want to return an array to the python should may be it would be a good idea to use a boost::python::dict, something like...

```
boost::python::dict arr;

int i = 0;
for (auto &item: array) {
    arr[i] = item;
    ++i;
}

return arr;
```